# How was Shri Ved Vyas able to write all scriptures?

Tags: rama, sita, ramanand, srisampraday, vedvyas

How was Shi Ved Vyas Ji able to write all scriptures?

Answer (score 1):

When Śrī Ved Vyās Ji decided to complete the task for which he was incarnated, he was full of confusion how to start any writing? what should I take reference to write Veda-s, Vedant, Brahma Sūtra, All Purān & Up-Purān etc.? That's Maa Sarswati appeared in front of Śrī Ved Vyās & guided him to read Śrī Rām Charitra as that is the “काव्यबीजं सनातनम्" means the most primeval poem seed ;

पठ रामायणं व्यास काव्यबीजं सनातनम्।
यत्र रामचरित्रं स्यात् तदहं तत्र शक्तिमान् ॥

Purport:— Bhagavati Saraswati instructed Sage Vedavyāsa: O' Vyasa! Study the eternal seed of all scriptures, Srimad Ramayana! Where there is Śrī Rāmacharitam (the divine exploits or glories of Śrī Rāma), I (Saraswati) am always there!

(Brihad Dharma Purāna, 1.30.47,51)

Than Śrī Ved-Vyās read the whole Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam to be able to write, as said;

रामायणं पाठितं मे प्रसन्नोऽस्मि कृतस्त्वया।
करिष्यामि पुराणानि महाभारतमेव च॥

Purport:— After happily studying Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇa the eternal seed of all scriptures, Sage Ved-Vyasa composed Mahabharata and all Puranas.

(Brihad Dharma Purāna 1.30,55)

Infact Veda-s too says to study Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam:—

देवस्य पश्य काव्यं न ममार न जीर्यति ।

Purport:— Look at that divine Kāvya (Rāmāyaṇa) of the Supreme Being (Śrī Rām) which never get destroyed and outdated.

(Atharvavedā. 10.8.32)

Before Śrī Rāma, most of the incarnations of Bhagavān Śrī Vishnu such as Trivikrama, Vārāha, Narsimha, etc. were already happened, however no scripture was composed in order to account the glorious exploits of those incarnations. The Ādi-Kāvya (Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇa) was composed to expound 'Ved-Purusa, the Brahm of Upanishad is Śrī Rām'. The divine sage Nārad and Maharshi Vālmīki, both accepted Śrī Rāmāyaṇa is completely in accordance of Vedas. Maharshi Vālmīki composed Śrī Rāmāyaṇa to reinforce the deep imports of Vedas. Thus, a direct inference can be deduced from it - 'Sri Ram is the main purport of Vedas, Vedas sings the glory of Sri Ram alone, he is the Purusa of Purusa-Sukta, Purusa-Sukta is reconfirmed for Sri Ram in Śrī Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa, he is the all pervading eternal-Vishnu, he is the Aadi-Dev (Primeval lord), He is Narayana (the abode of all beings). The Brahm of Bhagavati Shruti is explained and expounded by Śrī Rāmāyaṇa.

रामायणमहाकाव्यमादौ वाल्मीकिना कृतं ।
तन्मूलं सर्वकाव्यानमितिहासपुराणयोः॥

Purport:— Maharshi Vālmīki composed the first Kāvya of the world, Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇa, which is the eternal seed of all other scriptures, Kāvya-s, Itihasa (Mahābhārat) and Purāṇas.

(Brihad Dharma Purāna, Purvārdha 22.27)

Śrī Kāli Dās has also said the same thing in his Rahuvansha in first Canto;

अथवा कृतवागद्वारे वंशेऽस्मिन् पूर्वसूरिभिः ।

Purport:— It is universally accepted that later works have been written on the model of the Ramayana.

As Śrī Rām is the Original Personality Of Godhead same like his Kāvya is also the Original model for all scriptures.

That's why Śrī Ved-Vyās has praised Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam in his every writing. He has said in Śrīmad Padma Purān that Veda is not Veda, that Purān is not Purān, that Saṃhitā is not Saṃhitā where Śrī Rām is not present.

Basically Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam is not a in general scripture, this is a Vēda in ITSELF. In Sanatan Dharma, Valmiki Ramayana is treated as Itihasa (history), the biography of supreme personality and the Pramana (the means of valid knowledge) which expounds the Vedas. One of the most important facts about Srimad Valmiki Ramayana is 'It is the first scripture after Vedas, composed by a Brahm-jnani sage Valmiki in order to expound and reinforce the meanings of Vedas.' As Brahman or Purusa is the main purport of Vedas, similarly Sri Ram is the main purport of Valmiki Ramayana as it is completely based upon Sri Ram's life; in the begining (with the quest about the Purusa being perfect in 16 qualities, on the Pattern of the quest about Brahman in Brahm-Sutra), the middle and the end (reconfirmation from BrahmA and Shiva) of Valmiki Ramayana, Sri Ram is identified as the Purusa (the supreme personality) or Aadi-Purusa (the primeval lord), and the imperishable Brahman.

Srimad Valmiki Ramayana is the most authoritative scripture after Bhagavati-Shruti, Purva-Bhaag of Veda i.e. the Dharma (righteous duties) is decided by Sri Ram's sublime conduct and Uttar-Bhag of Vedas i.e. Brahman himself is Sri Ram! Srimad Valmiki Ramayana is the incarnation of Vedas itself.

वेदवेद्ये परेपुंसि जाते दशरथात्मजे।
वेदः प्राचेतसादासीत् साक्षाद् रामायणात्मना॥
तस्माद्रामायणं देवि! वेद एव न संशयः॥

Purport: Supreme being is known through Vedas. When that Supreme being of Vedas born as son of Dasratha (Śrī Rām) in Ayodhya, that time all Vedas manifested themselves through the mouth of sage Valmiki, the son of sage Prachetus, directly as the Ramayana. Therefore, O' Devi, there is no doubt that Sri Ramayana is Vedas ITSELF.

[Valmiki Ramayana Mangalacharan and Agastya Samhita]

नास्ति रामायणात्परम्॥

Purport: No other scripture exists beyond Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇa.

(Skanda Purana Uttarakhand Ra• Ma• 5-21)

रामायणाद काव्यं सर्व वेदार्थ सम्मतम्

Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam is in accordance with meaning of Vedās.

(Skanda Purana Uttarakhand Ra• Ma• 5-64)

स तु मेधाविनौ दृष्ट्वा वेदेषु परिनिष्ठितौ।
वेदोपबृंहणार्थाय तावग्राहयत प्रभु:।।

Translation:—

Valmiki, the master, having found both Kusa and Lava endowed with intellect and accomplished in the Vedas initiated them into the Ramayana composed by him for explaining the meaning of the Vedas.

(Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam 1.4.6)

गायत्र्याश्च स्वरूपं तद्रामायणमनुत्तमम् ।।

Translation:—

And that excellent Rāmāyaṇa is the form of Gayatri. (Which means the Lord for whome Gayatri Mantra is dedicated is non other than Śrī Rāma as Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam is the expended form of Gayatri Mantra.)

(Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam 7.111.17)

Infact Prapatti Darshan Sutra 12 says-

उभयोरनयोः रामायणैव श्रेष्ठः ॥

In both the histories (Rāmāyaṇam & Mahabharata), Śrī Rāmāyaṇam is definitely the best.

Same is also confirmed by Vachan Bhushan, Sutra 5:—

इतिहास श्रेष्ठेन रामायणेन कारागृह वास कर्त्या वैभव उच्यते ।

Among the Itihāsa-s (Śrī Rāmāyaṇa, Śrī Mahābhārata, etc), Śrī Rāmāyaṇa has the superior authority, through Śrī Rāmāyaṇa the true glory of Śrī Sītā Jī who made herself in captive of Rāvaṇ (to reveal the true glory of Sri Ram), is told.

रामायणं वेदसमं श्राद्धेषु श्रावयेद बुधः ।।

Translation:—

A wise man should recite Ramayana which is equal to the Vedas during shrādha.

(Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam 7.111.4)

इदं पवित्रं पापघ्नं पुण्यं वेदैश्च सम्मितम् ।
य: पठेद्रामचरितं सर्वपापै: प्रमुच्यते ।।

Translation:—

This story of Rama is sacred and holy. It destroys sins and is equal to the Vedas. Whosoever reads it will be freed from all sins.

(Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam 1.1.98)

And infact their was another reason for Śrī Ved-Vyās to choose Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam as a model scripture as Ved-Vyās comes under Śrī Saṁpradāya (Śrī Rāmānanda Saṁpradāya) as their 7th Ācharya & without worshipping your Guru you cannot move forward. As in Śrī Saṁpradāya Śrī Śrī SītāRām are the First & Second Ācharya therefore without getting their blessings he can't move a inch.

इममेव मनुं पूर्व साकेतपतिर्मामवोचत् अहं हनुमते मम प्रियाय प्रियतराय । स वेद वेदिने ब्रह्मणे स वशिष्ठाय स पराशराय । स व्यासाय । स शुकाय इत्येषोपनिषत् । इत्येषाग्रह्मविद्या ।

Here Śrimati Sītā Maharani is telling that she got Mantra from Saket Pati Śrī Rāma after than she passed it to his beloved bhakt Śrī Hanuman after that Sri Hanuman ji passed it to Brahmā ji from Brahmā ji to Vashistha Ji from Vashistha Ji to Parāshara Ji from Parāshara Ji to Ved-Vyäsa Ji and than to Shukacharya Ji.

(Atharvavedā Maithili Maha Upanishad)

Śrīmad Ved-Vyās appeared by the will of Śrī Rām:—

भविष्यंति कलौ घोरे जीवा हरिबहिर्मुखाः।
रामाऽज्ञया हनूमान् वै मध्वाचार्यः प्रभाकरः॥
शंकरः शंकरः साक्षाद्वचासो नारायणः स्वयम्।
शेषो रामानुजो रामो रामदत्तो भविष्यति॥

Meaning:~ In the great Kali Yuga, all living beings will turn away from God, then by the order of Śrī Rāma, Hanuman ji will definitely incarnate as Madhwacharya ji, Shankar ji will be Shankaracharya and Ved-Vyas ji himself will be Nārāyana. Sesha ji (Lakshman ji) would be Śrīmad Ramanujaswami and Śrī Rama himself would be Śrīmad Rāmānandacharya (Ramdatta).

(Śrī Sada Shiv Samhita 8.9.12/13)

Thank You For Reading

Answer (score 0):

Veda Vyasa is an incarnation of Lord Vishnu himself.

***Know Kṛṣṇa Dvaipāyana Vyāsa to be Lord Nārāyaṇa.** O tiger among men, who else indeed, could be the creator of the Mahābhārata? Who moreover could enunciate dharmas of various kinds but He the Lord?*

Mahābhārata 12.334.1-17

Hence nobody else could have done such a task except Lord Narayana himself. Lord Narayana as Vyasa complied the Vedas, wrote Mahabharata and the Puranas.

Answer (score -1):

Veda-Vyasa was able to write all the scriptures due to the boon of Bhagawān Shiva only.

**Sri Shiva Purana 5.2.:**

> ***15. The sage Vedavyāsa who had acquired unequalled glory propitiated him (Bhagawān Shiva) and attained knowledge of the three times—past, present and future.***

**The Mahabharata Book 13: Anusasana Parva.: SECTION XVIII.:**

> *"Parasara said,--'In former times I gratified Sarva, O king. I then cherished the desire of obtaining a son that would be possessed of great ascetic merit, endued with superior energy, and addressed to high Yoga, that would earn world-wide fame, arrange the Vedas, and become the home of prosperity, that would be devoted to the Vedas and the Brahmanas and be distinguished for compassion. Even such a son was desired by me from Maheswara. Knowing that this was the wish of my heart, that foremost of Deities said unto me.--Through the fruition of that object of thine which thou wishest to obtain from me, **thou shalt have a son of the name of Krishna. In that creation which shall be known after the name of Savarni-Manu, that son of thine shall be reckoned among the seven Rishis. He shall arrange the Vedas, and be the propagator of Kuru's race. He shall, besides, be the author of the ancient histories and do good to the universe. Endued with severe penances, he shall, again, be the dear friend of Sakra. Freed from diseases of every kind, that son of thine, O Parasara, shall besides, be immortal.**--Having said these words, the great Deity disappeared there and then. Even such is the good, O Yudhishthira, that I have obtained from that indestructible and immutable God, endued with the highest penances and supreme energy.'*

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..