Is Bhagavad Gita only from the 15th century?

The 11th century Mahabharata manuscript preserved in Bhandarkar Oriental Research Institute Pune does not seem to contain this Bhagavad Gita. There are also apparently many versions of MBH and the text may have been evolving.
The oldest evidence of Bhagavad Gita is only from 1492 (pic above) and kept in England.
So is BG only a work from 1492? - Almost 2000 years after Panini laid down the rules of Sanskrit grammar?
Why didn't the older MBH versions have this work?

Just because the oldest version of a text available now dates to a certain year doesn't means that the same text didn't exist prior to that date. Adi Shankara (died in 820) & Ramanuja (died in 1137) composed commentaries on the Gita, which is enough refutation of your views. Besides, absence of the Gita in some manuscripts of Mahabharata can br attributed to factors like loss of pages & facts like the Gita being in greater circulation as an independent text (like nowadays), hence it not being required by the scribe to be copied again.

@অনু Which century is the oldest manuscript of the commentaries by Ramanuja & Shankar from? Surely it can't be before 1492 - it must be a recently written book being fraudulently told as a 12th century work! Just like Arthashastra. Prove me wrong - show me a commentary that is actually carbon dated to anytime before 1492................ also since BG was not part of MBH and there were many versions it only proves it was a work in progress. There is no proof it was sold separately nor is there any reason to believe that since it did not exist

Vyasa taught different parts of the Mahabharata to his shishyas. After 50 years of research, a critical edition of the Mahabharata is already released by bori in 1966 which includes the Gita (refer to Bibek Debroy's list of parvas in his translation of the Mahabharata). If you have evidence, you can reach out to bori explaining how the Gita is interpolated. There's already sufficient evidence on this topic: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45032/34973  Periyazhwar, a 7th century poet makes a direct reference to Krishna as a teacher who taught on the battlefield and saved the Pandavas.

Using some book to support an argument is not sufficient. On the other side, Acharyas from various schools and recent Indologists have spent a lifetime in research and accepted that the Bhishma Parva's Bhagavad Gita has remained almost the same with very minor change of words over the centuries and thus written commentaries on it for the welfare of mankind. Also, you do not speak anything about its subject matter and its alignment with the the Vedas and Upanishads. Hence, I'll conclude that this post is only a Vitaṇḍāvāda and not an inquiry arising from a desire to learn.

@HariHara It's not an argument it's just a FACT that there is zero proof for any BG copy dated before 1492 and it's also a FACT that BG does not exist in the oldest MBH - which isn't very old either mind you! This "lifetime in research" argument does not hold in front of hard scientific facts. Aristotle, Aryan Invasion theorists, Christian propagandists, Islamic scholars etc also spend "a lifetime doing research" - most of that research is unscientific or plain fraud.

Mahabharata (MBH) from Bhandarkar Oriental Research Institute (BORI) contains Bhagwad Gita (BG). See page 23 in  https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mahabharata-bori.html -> Devanagari ६ भीष्मपर्वम्...How are you so sure that all manuscripts of BORI doesn't contain BG???

I’m voting to close this question because OP is asking carbon-dating proofs instead of proofs from scriptures or Acharyas` work. Hence, this Q is off topic here may be better suited for some other SE site.

Without even getting into the issue of dating of Bhagwad Gita, the ridiculous assertions of the questioner (who seems is more interested in defaming Hinduism than asking questions) will he refuted.
There are dozens of commentaries on the Bhagwad Gita that are older than the 15th Century.  Adi Shankara (8th Century) wrote a full commentary on Gita. Similarly Ramanujacharya (11th Century), Madhavacharya (13th Century) have written full commentaries on Gita. Abhinavagupta (10th Century) writes a full commentary on the Gita. Jnaneshwar (13th Century) authored the Jnaneshwari which is a commentary on the Bhagwad Gita. Gitarth Sangraha of Yamunacharya (10th Century) is another full commentary on the Gita. Nimbarka (12th Century) again wrote commentary on Gita. Kadambari by Banbhatta (7th Century) mentions both Gita and Mahabharata in a single Shloka.
Further, all the commentaries post Shankara (and including Shankara) are absolutely consistent with each other to every single Shloka on the Gita. This implies atleast by Shankara's Era (8th Century), there was a single version of Gita available widely from North to South India that was commented upon by all the philosophers. That is the version of the present Gita available
with us dates back to atleast 8th Century CE.
PS. Manuscript dating is never used to identify the date of any literary work due to the loss of older manuscripts, purely due to the fact that preserving bark/paper is extremely difficult, especially in the hot and humid climatic conditions of India. Linguistic analysis of the Sanskrit used in Gita places it not later than 400 BCE. The mention of Gita and Mahabharata together in Kadambari of Banbhatta, which is a purely romantic novel work is enough to conclude that by the 7th Century, Gita as embedded in Mahabharata was an extremely popular text that even playwrights were well versed in.

Show some evidence that these commentaries are authentic & carbon dated to anytime before 1492 or before 1300. These are all very recent books fraudulently said to be medieval works. Their attribution to supposed medieval people is fake. Just like Arthashastra

@JaiHo - Read the studies of scholars like Jeaneane Fowler, J. A. B. van Buitenen, Kashi Nath Upadhyaya, Arvind Sharma etc.

@GokulRenjith If there is a specific study - name it, state the year, publication and what was the DATE arrived at after carbon dating? Fowler and Van Buitenen are/were humanities professors who probably could not do any carbon dating of commentaries. "Upadhyay" and "Sharma" are Brahmin names so they are as reliable as Arab Islamic writers are reliable for Quranic history. So far there is no commentary dated older than 1492. It does not exist because BG never existed in older MBH versions

@JaiHo - You are the one claiming it all as fake. So it's your responsibility to prove your claim. One manuscript doesn't mean anything. Not a single legitimate historian has ever claimed that Gita is from the 15th century.

@GokulRenjith All historians know that there is no evidence prior to 1492. I have already provided the proof from Oxford University and Bhandarkar Oriental Research Institute......... You are the only ones who have ZERO PROOF for even 550 years, let alone that 5500 years fraud claim.

@JaiHo - No legitimate Historian, not a single one has ever made such a claim. You have also proven absolutely nothing other than one manuscript which literally means nothing. Poor attempt at trolling.

Name ONE historian claiming he/she has seen scientific carbon dated evidence of a manuscript of BG and it's fraud commentaries before 1492 or 1300..... or you are lying. And provide the study name, date, publication and date arrived at. Thanks

@JaiHo - Name one legitimate historian who says that Gita is from the 15th century.

@GokulRenjith The oldest ever copy is well known at Oxford University to be from 1492. Even Prof. PR Mukund - Professor Emeritus at Rochester Institute of Technology - knows about it. Everyone also knows the Devnagri script did not exist much before the 9th century............ but ok it's clear you have no evidence of anything before the 15th century so you cannot answer the question.

@JaiHo - So you have no answer other than the stupid manuscript claim. Good to know.

He calls it "stupid" but in the hierarchy of different forms of historical and scientific evidence this is right at the top. The other stuff is only guesswork based on misinformation and not classed as evidence at all.

@JaiHo - All historians again agree that Gita is far older. So people who do these research all disagree with you.

Not this version, and not at to research centres like Oxford at any rate. Historians doing linguistic guesswork are NOT a primary source of scientific evidence. They are just doing guesswork and have no evidence. Even using linguistic guesswork they generally only date it between the 4th century BCE to 4th century AD. Which is totally against the 5500BCE fraud claim.

@JaiHo - I would rather trust actual historians than some random person on internet.

Scientific evidence, historical proof of MBH versions and proof from foreign travellers to India that BG never existed during 11th century (Abu-Saleh).......  vs linguistic guesswork with no evidence. Humanities professors are known for poor and unscientific work.

@JaiHo - Decades of research by numerous Historians proving the antiquity of Gita vs some guy on internet.

Just like science, historical manuscripts and proof from foreigners........... vs decades of guesswork by Christian historians, Islamic scholars etc. trying to prove things like Biblical events were real  Except in this case even these guesswork academics agree it took centuries of interpolations to finish the work

@JaiHo - Writings of Indian saints about Gita vs random troll in Internet

Hahaha a random Hindutva fraud / Indian scammer falsely claiming his recent and interpolated books are made by his God!  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/54649/how-was-shri-ved-vyas-able-to-write-all-scriptures/54870#54870
